# Manually update for android app

Tags: android, google-play

I developed an app, it have an internal database and I want to update this database. I want that when a user will update the app throught play store, he has to update it manually. How I do this?

Comment: Why cant you update the database automatically when they update the app? Why do you want to do it manually? Did you try google?

Comment: I have a class that load the database when the user installs the app but how can I detect when is updated?

Comment: You have version numbers of your database too. So in the oncreate of your database helper, you tell it its version 2 now. Then the update method will trigger, in which case you can check if it was version 1, and now version 2, and add accordingly, the new modifications to the database file